# How to delete paid or posted invoices from odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I am trying to delete paid invoices from odoo but it throws exception **"can't delete posted invoice"**. Is there any way to delete inovice from odoo?

This is the exception when I tried to delete invoice.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBRD1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the ***account_cancel*** module. It will allow you to configure your journal(s) with the possibility to cancel entries (a new checkbox will be visible on the journal configuration).

Then, you will be able to cancel an invoice (the status will then be "cancelled") and as soon as the invoice is cancelled you can set it back to draft..

But as soon as an invoice has been confirmed, you won't be able to delete it permanently (the invoice number stays reserved for that invoice)

Comment: Thanks @adam strauss to give solution.